# A hash key must be followed by a colon (:) syntax error

Tags: entries, craft3

Trying to get entries between two dates and am getting: 'A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token "operator" of value "~" ("punctuation" expected with value ":")'

```
{% set posts = craft.entries({
    section: animal,
    orderBy: "postDate" })  %}


{% set puppyAnimals = posts({
    animalDateOfBirth: 'and',  ">= " ~ now|date , '<=' ~ now|date_modify('-1 year')|date })  %}
```

It's Craft 3 so I may just have the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You're nearly there! The `and` query you’re building just needs to be declared as an array:

```
{% set puppyAnimals = craft.entries({
    section: 'animals',
    orderBy: 'postDate',
    animalDateOfBirth: ['and',  "<= #{now | atom}", ">= #{now | date_modify('-1 year') | atom}"]
}).all()  %}
```

The brackets around the value provided for `animalDateOfBirth` was being interpreted as a single string, followed by a missing key.

(I also opted for Twig’s interpolation syntax to make the series of array elements a little clearer, and used the `atom` filter to produce fully-qualified dates)

> One more note: I switched the greater-than and less-than operators, as I suspect the query would have returned no results—(after today, but earlier than last year)!

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is definitely not the first time the array syntax has got me.

Comment: Follow up question: just trying to do {% set puppyAnimals = posts({}) tells me that "posts" isn't a function, but calling posts.search({}) give me Undefined index: query. Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry! Tapped this out on my phone hastily, and totally flubbed the actual syntax. Updated! You can perform the entire query in a single statement, as above… no need to do it in multiple calls. Good to note that the query this builds can't be used as a function, but it can have the initial properties set (via `{…}`), or by chaining method calls on it (the Craft docs use this "dot notation", like `craft.entries().myFieldName('myValue')`)

Comment: For anyone else stumbling upon this, be sure and check out the [Element Query](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/) documentation for some examples!

Comment: All good! That's exactly when I ended up doing {% set puppyPosts = posts.animalDateOfBirth(['and',  "<= #{now | date('c')}", ">= #{now | date_modify('-1 year') | date('c')}"]).all %}